# C++ for-loops to display a pattern

Tags: c++

So basically I have to make this pattern using for-loops:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*

two blank lines

   **********
    *********
     ********
      *******
       ******
        *****
         ****
          ***
           **
            *
Two blank lines
            *
           **
          ***
         ****
        *****
       ******
      *******
     ********
    *********
   **********
```

I'm not too sure if I need to define * as a variable.  I know I need to use increments and decrements to make this happen and also need to use the justification to line it up correctly.  Some feedback and help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? (And hooray for breaking a two-week silence from "how to print this pattern" questions!)

Comment: Post your code! By the way, `*` is only a character...

Comment: If you don't have any code yet, think about how many nested loops you need for this.

Comment: ahh it didn't format correctly.  Basically it goes up in number from 1-10 with the asterisks counting each line, goes back down to 1 line by line justified left.  The next shape is the opposite; justified right with numbers going from 10-1 then 1-10.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem are to teach you how to divide a problem into smaller one to create code that can be reused for multiple patterns.

For example, you could write a function that prints a line

```
void PrintLine(int length)
```

And you probably want to specify if you want the line on the left or right

```
void PrintLine(int length, bool left)
```

Then all that's left is to make the looping condition that is specific to the shape you are trying to display.

Comment: I think this is a good start, but you might want to add some references to `cout`, loops or similar basic things that help the questioner solve his problem.

Comment: I assumed he is at least getting taught the basics of the language and what he has trouble with is the logic.

Answer (score -1):

For the first shape:

```
int one=1;
boolean doit=true;
int counter=0;

while(doit)
{
  printf("\n");
  counter+=one;
  for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
  {
      printf("*");
  }
  if(counter>maxi)
  {
      printf("\n");
      for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)printf("*");
      one=-one;
  }
  if(counter==0)doit=false;

}
```

Comment: would u have to define maxi = 10?

Comment: Thats why i just post the first part ;)

Comment: You'll probably need to print `'\n'` somewhere for this to work. Just saying, let the OP do this at least.